# how do I create a table cell type following a certain pattern

Tags: tabularx

How do I define A, B, and E such that:

```
\begin{tabularx}(\linewidth){| A | B | E | E |}
\end{tabularx}
```

the width of 4th column = left adjusted, width of longest element in the column.

the width of 3rd column = left adjusted, width of longest element in the column.

the width of 2nd column = left adjusted, 1/3 of \linewdith.

the width of 1st column = left adjusted, \linewidth - the width of the 2nd column - the width of the 3rd column - the width of the 4th column

I think B could be:

```
\dimexpr (\linewidth-\arrayrulewidth)/3 - 2\tabcolsep - \arrayrulewidth\relax
```

E is l

But I don't know what A should be

Comment: `{| >{\raggedright}X | >{\raggedright}p{.33\linewidth} |  l  |  l |}`

Comment: Also consider the sibling package tabulary: (e.g.,  `\begin{tabulary}(\linewidth){Lp{.33\linewidth}ll}`   or maybe better, just `{LLll}`. However, with `tabulary` the width of the table will be  equal to `\linewidth` only if there not  enough contents to at least one linebreak in L column. Otherwise it will have the same effect that a  `l` lowercase column. This is not a drawback, but a feature to avoid inelegant too wide tables, but if you have another thoughts, stay ith tabularx.